# uiwebview ,objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

i want to pull the html content from a given webpage. when i run the code given below,it loads the entire browser... say... google.com... into the UIWebView..i want the html content to be shown in my UIWebView... i used `[webVieww stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"]` in `webViewDidFinishLoad`
its not pulling the content... did i make a mistake... if something is wrong I'd be glad if you guys could correct my code.

### icodeBrowserViewController.m

```
#import "icodeBrowserViewController.h"

@implementation icodeBrowserViewController

@synthesize webView,addressBar,activityIndicator;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://firesky.com"]]];
}

-(IBAction)gotoAddress:(id) sender
{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[addressBar text]];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [addressBar resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webVieww
{
    js_result=[webVieww stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Could you clean up the presentation of the code a bit? This is pretty hard to read. Just stick 4 spaces in front of each line. The preview window will show you what it's going to look like.

Comment: Do you want to get the raw html?

Comment: just the specific html content

Comment: When you make a request to an HTML server, you get a single 'file', which then might cause other files to be loaded, such as images, and whatnot. So, all you are getting is HTML content. Is it that you want the "interesting content" versus the header stuff and navigation and whatnot?

Comment: no i jst want the specific content using this tag"document.getElementByid(specific id name)"...de thing is the javascript in webviewDidfinishload is not getting loaded in webview....could u tell me what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use UITextView for this:

```
NSString *pageContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myGoogleURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
myUiTextView.text = pageContents;
```

Comment: I'd start with this, use some of the string manipulation functions to filter out the stuff you don't want, construct a new page (you'll need something to replace the framework you are removing, probably just <html> and <body> pairs), and then run it into loadHTMLString:baseURL: in your webView.